# PowerShell foreach loop with embedded if statement yields "cannot accept 'True' as positional parameter"

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a simple PS line to take the exported .csv of AD groups in particular "regions" we have set up, then take the GroupScope (universal vs. global), and depending on the scope of the group, write the "department" attribute as either "Universal" or "Global." The reason for doing so is to help identify between the 2 scopes within SharePoint.

```
$uni="Universal"
Import-csv \\usershare\user\me\output\groups.csv | foreach {Get-ADGroup -Identity $_.Name -Properties * | Set-ADGroup if($_.GroupScope -eq $uni){-replace @{department=$uni}}}
```

This is returning the following error message though:
"A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts the argument 'True.'"

I'm probably missing something simple here but I just started out and I'm self-teaching by trial and error mostly. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're use of the if block is not valid for what you are trying to accomplish, it will only return True or False and Set-ADGroup will not know what to do with that hence the error.

Try this:

```
$uni="Universal"
$csv = Import-Csv -Path '\\usershare\user\me\output\groups.csv'
foreach($i in $csv)
{
    if($i.GroupScope -eq $uni)
    {
        Get-ADGroup -Identity $i.Name -Properties 'department' |
            Set-ADGroup -Replace @{department=$uni}
    }
}
```

I've set properties to only pull department as a smaller scope will speed up the query.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was getting some part of the logic wrong. Appreciate your clarification and helping me understand the actual issue.